# Routing calls to a mobile phone with a Mi-Fi?

Tags: telephony, mifi

I am traveling to the U.S. soon & I am planning to buy a Mi-Fi and a prepaid SIM with a voice and data plan being included.

So, besides using the Mi-Fi as wireless data access point to which several devices should be able to connect, I wonder whether there is any way to route calls from the Mi-Fi to my Android smartphone and/or to trigger calls from my Android smartphone to that Mi-Fi?

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder whether there is any way to route calls from the Mi-Fi to my
>   Android smartphone and/or to trigger calls from my Android smartphone
>   to that Mi-Fi?

To my knowledge, no. The only way you could potentially use Mi-Fi data for calls is to use some kind of VoIP service such as Skype. Meaning you install Skype on your phone, get a Skype number & then use the Wi-Fi connection you get from the Mi-Fi to make & receive calls. Seems complex but might be just what you need if you want to avoid overseas roaming charges.